# Count Words Function not giving correct answers

Tags: java

I am writing a Count Words function, but every time there is a single letter it doesn't count the first word in the sentence. The min and max inputs are for the maximum characters and minimum characters that the word can be. Any help or suggestions would be awesome.

```
public static int countWords (String word, int min, int max)
{
    int WordCount = 0;
    int CharacterCount = 0;
    int StringLength = word.length();
    int n = 0;

    while (StringLength > 0)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(n)))
        {
            CharacterCount = CharacterCount + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CharacterCount >= min && CharacterCount <= max)
            {
                WordCount = WordCount + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                WordCount = WordCount;
            }
        CharacterCount = 0; 
        }
    n = n + 1;  
    StringLength = StringLength - 1;
    }
return WordCount;   
}
```

Comment: What values are used as arguments. Show typical example of arguments and WordCount you got.

Comment: The one I am currently getting stuck on is countWords("a b c", 1, 1), it says there are only two words, and when only a is entered I am getting zero, so for some reason it isn't counting the first word if it is just a letter.

Comment: Sounds like you might be forgetting to add the last word at the end of the string :)  PS: the `else {WordCount = WordCount}` is superfluous.  Lose it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove unnecessary else block, And add another `if` at the end of the while loop. The problem was that the final word is not correctly counted.

```
public class WordCount {

    public static int countWords (String word, int min, int max)
    {
        int WordCount = 0;
        int CharacterCount = 0;
        int StringLength = word.length();
        int n = 0;

        while (StringLength > 0)
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(n)))
            {
                CharacterCount = CharacterCount + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (CharacterCount >= min && CharacterCount <= max)
                {
                    WordCount = WordCount + 1;   
                }
                CharacterCount = 0;
            }
            n = n + 1;  
            StringLength = StringLength - 1;
        }
        if ( CharacterCount > 0 ) {
            WordCount++;
        }

        return WordCount;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( countWords("a b c", 1, 1) );
        System.out.println( countWords("This is a string", 1, 100) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is only a single char and is actually a letter, then you will only ever enter into the first if statement, setting `CharacterCount` to 1.

`WordCount` will still remain at 0

Is the `else` necessary?

Comment: No, the else statement isn't necessary, but I just like to have it there for some odd reason.